# How to remove a file with post-render in Quarto

Tags: r, quarto

From [Quarto docs](https://quarto.org/docs/projects/scripts.html):

> Note that pre-render and post-render also support arbitrary shell
> commands. So you could for example use make to do data preparation
> this way:
>
> ```
> project:
>  type: website
>  pre-render: make prepare
> ```

But both

```
post-render:
    - del *.pdf
    - rm *.pdf
```

returns `ERROR: Error executing 'del': program not found` (same with `rm`). How to delete a file using `post-render`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have tried with `rm`, it seems to me that wildcard is not working (I am not sure why). That is, the following works,

```yaml
post-render: 
  - rm test.pdf test1.pdf
```

while the following does not,

```yaml
post-render: 
  - rm *.pdf
```

gives the following error,

```bash
rm: cannot remove '*.pdf': No such file or directory
```

However, instead of passing direct shell command, you can write python/R script to remove files and use that in `post-render`. For example, you can use the following R script to remove all the pdf files in the quarto website project directory.

**remove-files.R**

```r
library(fs)

# list all pdf files in the project directory.
files_to_be_deleted <- list.files(pattern = "*.pdf")

file_delete(files_to_be_deleted)
message(paste(files_to_be_deleted, "is deleted\n"))
```

**_quarto.yaml**

```yaml
project:
  type: website
  post-render: 
    - remove-files.R
```